# WordPress AMP doesn't show GitHub Gist

Tags: wordpress, github

AMP official plugin is installed on WordPress and some GitHub Gists added to posts by custom HTML. AMP doesn't show GitHub Gists.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in this link: https://www.puresourcecode.com/tools/embed-github-gists-on-wordpress/ but example of usage was wrong.
It should be like this: [gist id="1c3fd17a1be7b20cda9d85d32da1cbd9"]